# Getting location of Tweets using twitteR package

Tags: r, twitter

I am using the twitteR package to extract specific tweets in R and I want to produce a spatial map. For example, a map of tweets of a certain disease. How can I get the location of the tweets? The "searchTwitter" function is able to extract from a certain location by specifying the latitude, longitude and search radius but I am not able to get the latitude/longitude location of each tweet.

A simple example:

```
library("twitteR")
library(stringr)
ecoli2=searchTwitter("e. coli + e.coli",lang="en",n=25,since='2011-11-24')
```

Then, when I try to extract the latitude and longitude of the tweets, I get "character(0)" as shown below:

```
sapply(ecoli2, function(x) x$getLongitude())[1:3] # showing the first three
[[1]]
character(0)

[[2]]
character(0)

[[3]]
character(0)
```

Comment: What code have you written? What errors are you getting?

Comment: have you tried to send your query via the [twitter api console tool](https://dev.twitter.com/rest/tools/console)? There you can see how your request should come back.

Answer (score -1):

In case one finds this helpful, I used the following functions to get time, latitude and longitude:

```
ecoli=searchTwitter("e. coli + e.coli",lang="en",n=20000,since='2011-11-1',until ='2011-12-30',geocode='37,-96,2000mi')

ecolitext=sapply(ecoli, function(x) x$getText())
ecolilat=sapply(ecoli, function(x) as.numeric(x$getLatitude()))
ecolilon=sapply(ecoli, function(x) as.numeric(x$getLongitude()))
ecolidate=lapply(ecoli, function(x) x$getCreated())
ecolidate =sapply(ecolidate, function(x) as.character(as.Date(x)))

ecoli2=as.data.frame(cbind(tweet=ecolitext,date=ecolidate,lat=ecolilat,lon=ecolilon))
```